# How to execute a GraphQL query from a Next.js app?

Tags: api, next.js, graphql, routes

I have this Insomnia GraphQL command that I'm trying to put into a Next.js app. This is the actual API call that I've been running in Insomnia that I plan on moving into my Next.js app.

```
query getCharacters {
  characters(page: 1) {
    info {
      count
    }
    results {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

It's a super simple function... Here's what it looks like in Insomnia:
[image: query in graphiql]

I found this example code for doing GraphQL function calls with Next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-graphql. It requires `typeDefs` and `resolvers` to create a schema. I'm unfamiliar with this type of function call as I have always used simple rest APIs for previous apps.

I don't know what the `typeDefs` and `resolvers` are for https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql 's `getCharacters` function?

Maybe I'm going about this incorrectly and I don't actually need to get `getCharacter`'s `typeDefs` and `resolvers`. If I'm approaching this incorrectly, can someone show me how to execute this `getCharacters` function in a next.js graphql function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is going to act as a GraphQL *client.* *TypeDefs* and *resolvers* are written on the *server.* For example  https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql is the GraphQL server that you are trying to connect to and `getCharacters` is a particular *query* on that server.

There are many ways to execute a GraphQL query from next.js - these are well described in this [article](https://hygraph.com/blog/nextjs-graphql). I recommend using the [apollo-client](https://hygraph.com/blog/nextjs-graphql#apollo-client) method rather than the lower level `fetch` or `axios.`